# jQuery losing $(this) object after DOM update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

---

**JS**

```
$('ul').on('hover', 'li', function(){
 // ajax call to get data
 // and put the response data into current li as html
 $(this).html(data);
 // here $(this) is lost if both event fire at same time and DOM updated via second ajax response
});

$( window ).scroll(function() {
  // ajax call to get the next content and append into list
  $( "ul" ).append( data );
});
```

I am loading data via ajax.

There are two events 
(1) hover on li and 
(2) scroll

If user fires both events at the same time and response of scroll ajax call comes first then elements into DOM is appended, and then response of second ajax call came, and getting `$(this)` lost in success callback.

Comment: `$('ul li').live('hover' ...` is about as wrong as it gets, `hover` is not an event and `live()` is deprecated and removed from jQuery. Not that it solves the issue, just saying.

Comment: [As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Yes I am using "on", but what is the solution of problem ?

Comment: I can't understand the issue. Where exactly is the AJAX request? I don't see it. How is `this` being lost? Its value does not change. The value of `this` inside a different callback is likely going to be different, but I don't see where that would be in your code.

Comment: Have you tried saving $(this) in a variable before making the ajax call?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here problem was with other part of JavaScript code that was changing the html in DOM, that was the problem of loosing the event, jQuery append works fine, but somewhere else html was changing with "**innerHTML**"

**Problem:**

```
document.getElementById("ul_id").innerHTML = "<ul>...............</ul>";
```

**Solved Problem using jQuery append**

```
 $('#ul_id').append("<li>html code...</li>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be `context:this,` should be used in the ajax call, so if you are using `jQuery.ajax()` method then you can add `context` in the options of it:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'',
  ......
  context: this,
  ......
});
```

---

If you use `context` then the context provided in it will be available in all the callbacks of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that `$(this)` isn't the same after the ajax-call. $(this) changes depending on the context.

```
$('ul').on('hover', 'li', function(){
 var li_element = $(this);
 // ajax call to get data
 // and put the response data into current li as html

 // here $(this) is lost if both event fire at same time and DOM updated via second ajax response
 //li_element is equalent to $(this) when hovered, so try:
 li_element.html(data); 
});

$( window ).scroll(function() {
  // ajax call to get the next content and append into list
  $( "ul" ).append( data );
});
```